# Redirect specific page to HTTPS with HTACCESS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, ssl, https

i have this URL http://www.mysite.com/checkout/payment, well, i created a file htaccess to redirecting this page, when the URL is different of 'checkout/payment', the URL turns into a normal http.

But ever a problem occurs, the assets (JS, CSS, JPG, PNG) always are redirected to normal HTTP, how i fix this?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(checkout/pay)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (checkout/pay)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I think you better change the URLs for these resources so that they use a relative url for example instead of `<img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/header.png" />` then use `<img src="/images/header.png" />`. Or of course inject the suitable protocol (http / https).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following rules:

```
# Redirect checkout pay(ment) pages to https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/checkout/pay [NC]
RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirects all resources where the http referer field matches the checkout payment page.
# Weirdly enough I can't seem to use any server variables in the http referer regex. Please change it to match your host.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://www.mysite.com/checkout/pay [NC]
RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```